# Page position with pdfpages

Tags: pdfpages

Since I had problems `\include`-ing some .tex to my project I tried using the `pdfpages` package and the `\includepdf` command, but the pages are included displaced and I don't understand the `pdfpages` documentation (how to use the delta or what logical pages are). My code is simple:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,final,twoside,twocolumn,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\includepdf[pages=-]{file1}
\includepdf[pages=-]{file2}
\includepdf[pages=-]{file3}
\includepdf[pages=-]{file4}
```

Comment: Could you include an image of the displacement? Tell us a little more about the source and target documents. Does `file1` have the same layout as `file2`, `file3`, and `file4`? And how do these relate to the source that you're putting them in?

Comment: How can I show you an image? I have a pdf page of the full document but I don't know how to show it. The files have the same layout and they are jobs for a magazine (the main document).

Comment: What are the options you pass to the [`pdfpages` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) in your document preamble? Using no options (that is, just `\usepackage{pdfpages}`) and your `\includepdf` statements above inserts them as-is within the document without any offset.

Comment: I found the offset its wrong. Is there a way to tell the command to center the page?

Comment: You can adjust the offset of pages using the `offset` key-value. See p 3 of the [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf). However, the default is `offset=0 0`, so I don't understand why there is an incorrect offset in the first place. Without knowing more, it's not possible to help you.

Comment: I tried with other documents I have and I have the same problem.

Comment: As mentioned, I don't have enough information to help anymore. Until such time, read the documentation on how to move things around, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem: I was changing page layout with `\voffset`,`\hoffset`, `\headheight`, etc and, apparently, `pdfpages` don't likes that (ridiculous, Isn't it?). 
Wuth `\voffset = 0cm` and `\hoffset = 0cm` it works fine.